# UITableView data changes by typing the city name in FirstViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, datasource

I Use Swift 3
I have a **textfield** in my first **ViewController** and when I type name of the city I want it to open Pharmacies of that city in **tableView**

Example: When I type New York in **textField** and press enter it will go to **TableViewController** and will give a list of pharmacies in new york:

---

New York Pharmacy 1

New York Pharmacy 2

New York Pharmacy 3

---

When I go back and type California in **textField** and press enter it will go to the same **TableViewController** and will give a list of pharmacies in california:

California Pharmacy 1

California Pharmacy 2

California Pharmacy 3

---

I did it with two different **TableViewControllers** But I want to do it in one **TableViewController**

I don't know How to do it, need help

Comment: Where are your pharmacies list/data stored? I don't see why you need multiple data sources, just filter your data. there are many ways you could handle this

Comment: I just made two arrays for pharmacies, I don't know how to do that I tried to pass data but I could not one of my friends told me that it is possible with two data sources that's why I said two data sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end I found out how to do, and this is how I did:

```
@IBAction func GoPressed(_ sender: Any) {
            if textField.text == "New York" || textField.text == "new york" {
                let arrayForNewYork = ["New York Pharmacy 1","New York Pharmacy 2","New York Pharmacy 3"]
                performSegue(withIdentifier: "Go", sender: arrayForNewYork)
            }else if textField.text == "California" || textField.text == "california" {
                let arrayForCalifornia = ["California Pharmacy 1","California Pharmacy 2","California Pharmacy 3"]
                performSegue(withIdentifier: "Go", sender: arrayForCalifornia)
            }
```

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me :)

Answer (score 1):

As stated, there are a number of ways you could do this, the example I have provided below shows a single array of Pharmacy Objects (from the struct) in various locations. Then having a computed property which is a list filtered by the contents of a text field.

```
struct Pharmacy {
   name: String
   location: String
}

let pharmacies: [Pharmacy] = [
   Pharmacy(name: "California Pharmacy 1", location: "California"),
   Pharmacy(name: "California Pharmacy 2", location: "California"),
   Pharmacy(name: "California Pharmacy 3", location: "California"),
   Pharmacy(name: "New York Pharmacy 1", location: "New York"),
   Pharmacy(name: "New York Pharmacy 2", location: "New York"),
   Pharmacy(name: "New York Pharmacy 3", location: "New York")
]

var filteredPharmacies: [Pharmacy] { get {
   return self.pharmacies.filter({ $0.location == self.locationTextField.text })
}}
```

Note that this option as currently coded above would still need further work, if the textfield did not contain a location, there would be no results, you could address this by changing the filter, maybe like this...

```
var filteredPharmacies: [Pharmacy] { get {
   return self.locationTextField.isEmpty || self.pharmacies.filter({ $0.location == self.locationTextField.text })
}}
```

The main thing to take note of is that you can have a single list of sources and just filter them based on any filters you may have and just use the filtered data as your tableView data source.